# How can I test the POST request an external webhook makes to my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, vcr

Folks this is my scenario

There is this external webhook that I would like to test

Is there a way to use VCR or some other tool to record the POST request the webhook makes to my rails app so I can use it in Rspec to run my tests?

The webhook's body is long and very specific that's why I would like to record the request somehow

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried Requestbin and Charles to record the request but did not manage to make them work so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that when you say the problem input is "too long and too specific" what you mean is that it would be inconvenient to construct it inside a test: a simple solution is to put the post body into a separate file.

You can save an example POST body as a file under `test/` or `spec/` and then read it and [post to your app in a request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#providing-json-data):

```
post(
  my_webhook_path, 
  params: JSON.parse(File.read(path_to_json_file) # assuming the post body is JSON 
) 
# expect/assert some things about the effects/response of the request
```

In the docs you will see that you can also add headers, so it should be possible to construct the exact request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the VCR is the best tool for that. It's great for recording *outgoing* requests, not the incoming ones.

I'm guessing you already have a controller and an action that should accept those requests, make sure your app is running and accessible for the service that is going to ping you ([ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is great for that)

Then in your action do something like

```
def my_action_accepting_webhook_requests
  puts request_parameters
  puts query_parameters
end
```

You can just read from the console (or save to file) the params, decide if you want to hardcode it in the spec or save it as a file. And then in your [request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) you can re-use it and test your webhook.